# Weird black borders on renders Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm rendering an animation in Blender and getting these weird borders around the render, where it shows the world color or HDRi. But when I move the camera away from the object, the render comes out normal.

[image]

Comment: This does not seem like a common problem. It will probably be very hard to diagnose without seeing the file. You can edit the question and share the file using [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) .

Answer (score 1):

Eevee has many things that are limited to what the camera sees. That's why reflections can look this way when close to the camera because what they should reflect is literally non-existent.

To fix that, the simplest technique is to "[overscan](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/film.html)", render an area bigger than the camera.

You can enable this under *Properties Editor > Render tab > Film panel*.

Comment: I’ll try doing that and hopefully it will fix the issue

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I did increase overscan and it fixed the issue.